# How do I use Django's form framework for select options?

Tags: python, html, django, forms

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select

Here, it says I can do SELECT widgets. But how do I do that?
It doesn't show any example on how to write that field in python.

```
 <select>
   <option>option 1</option>
   <option>option 2</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (('Option 1', 'Option 1'),('Option 2', 'Option 2'),)
    field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    
print MyForm().as_p()

# out: <p><label for="id_field">Field:</label> <select name="field" id="id_field">\n<option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>\n<option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>\n</select></p>
```

Comment: It says: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices'

Comment: choices should be defined in a widget constructor

Comment: Thanks for fixing it TIMEX :P

Answer (score 14):

```
CHOICES= (
('ME', '1'),
('YOU', '2'),
('WE', '3'),
)
select = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=CHOICES))
```

Answer (score 13):

errx's solution was almost correct in my case, the following did work (django v1.7x):

```
CHOICES= (
('1','ME'),
('2','YOU'),
('3','WE'),
)
select = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=CHOICES)
```

The elements inside CHOICES correspond to ($option_value,$option_text).

Answer (score 3):

> Django 2.0

```
Options = [
        ('1', 'Hello'),
        ('2', 'World'),
      ]
category = forms.ChoiceField(label='Category', widget=forms.Select, choices=sample)
```

BTW tuple also works as same as list.

```
Options = (
        ('1', 'Hello'),
        ('2', 'World'),
     )
category = forms.ChoiceField(label='Category', widget=forms.Select, choices=sample)
```

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError when using this format in Django 2.1.15, search for question # 61037692