# Django: Slicing form data before "form.is_valid"

Tags: python, django, slice

I have a ModelForm, which saves and creates a new object for my class `Person`.
This class `Person` has an attr called `is_adult`.
Its value is a `model.CharField` with a `max_length=1`, where I save only values `Y` or `N` (Yes/No).

The problem is that this attr is rendered as a `Select` HTML field. In this Select field, the available choices are "Yes" and "No", therefore when the form is sent as a POST method it comes with a value of 2-3 length CharField, but its Model attr has a max_length of 1, so I need to slice those two options **before** checking `if form.is_valid()`. Otherwise the form is not accepted because it is posting with a value of 2-3 chars and it's expecting 1 char.

models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    is_adult = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=False, choices=ADULT_CHOICES, default='N')
```

choices.py:

```
ADULT_CHOICES= (
        (0, 'No'),
        (1, 'Yes'),
)
```

forms.py:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ["is_adult"]
        widgets = {
            'is_adult': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
        labels= {
            'is_adult': 'Is an adult?',
        }
```

And of course views.py is expecting 'Y' or 'N', and not 'Yes' or 'No'.
I tried to slice its string with the Python syntaxis, but I couldn't get the form field value before it gets rejected in "form.is_valid".
Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Django's form framework for select options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788388/how-do-i-use-djangos-form-framework-for-select-options)

Comment: It is not. All the answers are about the choice list, not about how to manage its data in the view

Comment: Because you are doing it wrong... see answer below. Then add the HTML from your rendered template with the form to your question. Specifically the <select> tag with the rendered <options> attributes.

Comment: Did that resolve your issue? If so, please mark answer.

Answer (score 0):

Marked as duplicate, but you should use a [choice form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield).

Change your forms.py to the following:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ["is_adult"]
        labels= {
            'is_adult': 'Is an adult?',
        }
```

The default behavior of the model form should use a form.ChoiceField which should automatically set your select options (in your HTML) to the correct 'Y' and 'N' values.

You should not need to slice anything, as Django should handle this for you.

When a ChoiceField is used your HTML should be rendered like this (note the option `values`):

```
<select>
  <option value="Y">Yes</option>
  <option value="N">No</option>
</select>
```

See duplicate question: [How do I use Django's form framework for select options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788388/how-do-i-use-djangos-form-framework-for-select-options)